# Ability to chat?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, chat

I'm new to the stack exchange sites and meta stack overflow. How do I get enough of a reputation in order to participate in chats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 20 rep on meta to participate in chat.meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Which he just got thanks to this question :-)

Comment: @Ivo Flipse That's a level of support i don't think people get very often.

Comment: I just "discovered" stack exchange 4 days ago when I ran across a mention on the Facebook Ubuntu group. It's already made my life better.

Answer (score 3):

On the other hand, if you have any existing high-rep account at one of the other sites (SO, SF, SU), then you can also just associate your meta account. You'll get a bonus of 100 rep. Check the *Accounts* tab in your user profile.

Comment: -1, OP doesn't have a qualifying account.

Comment: @Popu: Sorry, I can't smell that and I learn nothing from a downvote plus nitpick :)

Comment: how high does the high-rep account have to be?

Comment: @latho: according to the [faq](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) it's 200 points.

Comment: @Popu: I am still waiting for your instructive explanation how you can be 100% sure that he doesn't have a qualifying account. How about the unregistered ones at different browsers? How about registered ones using a different email/openid which he hasn't ever logged in for on the current browser? Can you please tell me how I can smell that?

Comment: @Balus, look at his comment on the accepted answer - " I just "discovered" stack exchange 4 days ago when I ran across a mention on the Facebook Ubuntu group. It's already made my life better." So, he is brand new, and his Ubuntu account doesn't have enough rep yet.

Comment: @jjnguy: *but, but, but* that comment was posted 30 seconds before my answer! ~sigh. Even then, in one day you can easily earn 200 rep.

Comment: @Balus, 31 seconds! `:p`

Comment: @Balus: it's technically possible that the OP has such an account.  But based on context -- i.e. what @jjnguy said -- it's _such_ an outside possibility that it's ignore-worthy.

Comment: @Popu: there's always such possibility. But how on earth is that worth a downvote? I didn't even *explicitly* state that he has such one account. Is my effort not appreciated? It this knowledge not valuable for others who happen to land on this question after a search? Or is it just because it's me? Should I change the nickname?

Comment: @Balus, for better or for worse, there's no objective definition of the appropriate weight of a downvote, especially on Meta.  It just seemed worth it to me in this case.

Comment: @Balus I've just tried this, but am still left with only a reputation of 1. I'd rather not needlessly create a question just for the sake of it. I'll sreach and see if this is a bug...

Comment: @matthed: you *really* need 20 rep. You must somehow have an association with stackexchange. Just post a helpful answer somewhere and you'll get votes.